# Search fails with special characters

Tags: 7, search

Searching is not working when the search string contains special characters.

For example, when we search *&$#%^@*, we are redirected to http://example.com/search/node/&$#%^@. There, if I search with some other text (e.g. *test*) we are still at http://example.com/search/node/&$#%^@.

I tried in different websites which are using the core Search module. It is failing in all websites.

Comment: That's probably a bug, would be best to report it to the issue queue on drupal.org if you've confirmed it happens on a stock install

Comment: To add to what @Clive said, you simply stating facts, without asking any explicit question. If you are asking for a confirmation, _Drupal Answers_ is not the place for this.

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually, this issue is fixed in latest version of Drupal 7 (i.e. 7.43). I tried it and its working perfectly with the 7.43 version.